# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in D:\php\Practice 1\index.php on line 61

Tags: php, syntax

```
$y = null;
$x = 2;
echo $x . "<br>";
echo $x = $x + 3 . '<br>';
echo $x = $x + 3 . "<br>";
```

here is my code. I cannot understand why it is happening. If I take `<br>` this code anyways will not work properly

I tried to avoid `<br>`, and I cannot understand the reason of this problem. In c++ for example it works properly

Comment: `<br>` is a string. `.` is a concatenation. So when you do `echo $x = $x + 3 . '<br>';` what you're really doing is changing `$x` to `5<br>`. The second time you do that exact same line, it won't work. You may want `echo ($x = $x + 3) . '<br>';` instead.

Comment: Or just echo <br> with separate line of code, like mouse sane people would do

Answer (score 0):

In your second `echo` you're taking the entirety of the expression on the right and assigning it to `$x`

That is, your adding 3 to $x and concatenating `<br` to the result. `$x` is now `5<br>`.

When you try it again in your third `echo` `$x` is now not a numeric value, hence the error.

Try

```
echo ($x = $x + 3) . "<br>";
```

Comment: Thank you, I found answer with the  help of your answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

So the solution was that I was trying to add two type of variables.
In:

```
echo $x = $x + 3 . '<br>';
```

I have `'<br>'` with one quotes and in the second one :

```
echo $x = $x + 3 . "<br>";
```

I have `"<br>"` with two quotes. It is because PHP take `<br>` also as a value for $x.